# Is there any method for finding the number of detected corners using Harris Corner Detector

Tags: python, opencv, corner-detection

I'm trying to find a number of detected corners in python using Harris Corner Detector in real time. I searched the whole internet but I couldn't find any link for that nor single post. You can suggest any other better method for detecting corners and counting detected corners. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I don't understand the question. There is a whole OpenCV tutorial on Harris in their docs: https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d4/d7d/tutorial_harris_detector.html

Comment: I read all documents. The harris corner function is showing all corners in image but i want the count. im not able to find count.

Answer (score 0):

The Harris Corner Detector is an image filter that yields a high response at corner points in an image.

If you look at the OpenCV tutorial on Harris, you notice the following code is used to draw circle around these high responses:

```
# Drawing a circle around corners
for i in range(dst_norm.shape[0]):
    for j in range(dst_norm.shape[1]):
        if int(dst_norm[i,j]) > thresh:
            cv.circle(dst_norm_scaled, (j,i), 5, (0), 2)
```

You can use the same code for counting up a counter instead of drawing a circle. As you can see, this involves coming up with a threshold value suited to your specific image data.